How to use service in Angular ngModule
Here is a shared module and I want to use translate service inside module but the problem here is that setCulture(translate.currentLang); the translate here is unknown.
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { inject, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import * as ejsTranslation from './ejs-translations.json';
import { L10n, setCulture } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';


setCulture(translate.currentLang);
L10n.load(ejsTranslation);

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [TranslateService]
})
export class SharedModule { }


Have you tried using APP_INITIALIZER?

You can try initializing on the module level, like so.
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { inject, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import * as ejsTranslation from './ejs-translations.json';
import { L10n, setCulture } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
...
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [TranslateService]
})
export class SharedModule { 
 constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
   setCulture(translate.currentLang);
 }
}

SyncFusion Code Reference
